# Cyrillic symbols in Latex

Tags: languages, bold, cyrillic, times, ukrainian

I have to translate a book. The book uses math fonts. I'm completely new to latex except using it in wikipedia articles.

When i add support for ukrainian language the layout is broken. Also there is a problem with boldness.

I prepared minimal example which reproduces the error with boldness:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[mtpcal,mtphrb,zswash,subscriptcorrection]{mtpro2}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\newcommand{\subheading}[1]{\subsubsection*{{\boldmath#1}}}
\subheading{Insertion sort}
\subheading{Сортування вставкою}

\end{document}
```

It produces this

[image]

If delete lines 2 and 3 it produces this

[image]

If delete lines 4 and 5 it produces this

[image]

How can i make it to use Cyrillic symbols along with `times`?

---

Just to check i changed `boldmath` to `textit` then i got

> Package inputenc Error:  Unicode char �\check@icr (U+3E8) (inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.

Comment: Unless there is a Cyrillic version of the `times` font you're out of luck, I think. Have you seen a `Cyrillic` Times yet? ;-) By the way, the `times` package is outdated anyway

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thanks, with what can i replace it then?

Comment: The font experts will show up with a solution, I am pretty sure

Comment: the example you've shown is ordinary text, not math, so i've changed the tag from `[boldmath]` to `[bold]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `times` package (besides being obsolete) doesn't provide a Cyrillic font.

With an up-to-date TeX system, you can use `tempora`, which provides a Times clone supporting both Cyrillic and Greek, besides Latin.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage{tempora}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} % I just have the lite version

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\newcommand{\subheading}[1]{\subsubsection*{{\boldmath#1}}}

\subheading{Insertion sort}
\subheading{Сортування вставкою}

\end{document}
```

[image]